# Neo4j Cypher query for a linked list to conditionally create a NEWEST_REPLY vs modifying NEWEST_REPLY to NEXT_REPLY

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a linked list of replies off of a Post that looks like this:

[image]

With the "first" reply in the list having a NEWEST_REPLY relationship to Post and subsequent replies having a NEXT_REPLY relationship. The query to get the above graph:

```
MATCH (p:Post {id: $postId})-[:NEWEST_REPLY|NEXT_REPLY*]->(r:Reply) 
return p, r
```

I want to create a cypher query that either

1. Creates a reply and creates the NEWEST_REPLY relationship when there are no replies OR
2. Creates a reply, deletes the current NEWEST_REPLY relationship, creates a NEXT_REPLY relationship to the previous NEWEST_REPLY and a NEWEST_REPLY relationship to the new Reply.

This statement:

```
MATCH (p:Post {id: $postId})-[rel:NEWEST_REPLY]->(previousNewestReply:Reply)
DELETE rel
CREATE (r:Reply { id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: $body, createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime() })
WITH r, p, previousNewestReply
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = $userId 
CREATE (r)<-[:WROTE]-(u)
CREATE (r)<-[:NEWEST_REPLY]-(p)
CREATE (r)-[:NEXT_REPLY]->(previousNewestReply)
RETURN u, p
```

achieves number 2.

What I now need to do is conditionally run this statement if the `rel` in `MATCH (p:Post {id: $postId})-[rel:NEWEST_REPLY]->(previousNewestReply:Reply)` exists, but if it does not exist, just create NEWEST_REPLY for the first time as well as creating the reply and the `User-[:WROTE]->Reply` relationship. I'm new to cypher and digging into MERGE, CASE, predicate functions and apoc.when() and not sure which would be the simplest and most appropriate.

Here's an attempt at using CASE:

```
MATCH (p:Post {id: "db7ee38c-fe60-430e-a7c7-0b2514401343"})
RETURN
CASE EXISTS( (p)-[rel:NEWEST_REPLY]->(replies:Reply) )
WHEN true  THEN DELETE rel CREATE (r:Reply { id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: "new with CASE1", createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime() }) WITH r, p, replies MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = "e14d409e-d970-4c5c-9cc7-3b224c774835" CREATE (r)<-[:WROTE]-(u) CREATE (r)<-[:NEWEST_REPLY]-(p) CREATE (r)-[:NEXT_REPLY]->(replies)
WHEN false THEN CREATE (r:Reply { id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: "new with CASE2", createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime() }) WITH r, p, previousNewestReply MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = "e14d409e-d970-4c5c-9cc7-3b224c774835" CREATE (r)<-[:WROTE]-(u) CREATE (r)<-[:NEWEST_REPLY]-(p) END
AS result;
```

And running into the following SyntaxError:

```
Invalid input 'r': expected whitespace, comment, '{', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a parameter (old syntax), a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, WHEN, ELSE or END (line 4, column 24 (offset: 145))
"WHEN true  THEN DELETE rel CREATE (r:Reply { id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: "new with CASE1", createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime() }) WITH r, p, replies MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = "e14d409e-d970-4c5c-9cc7-3b224c774835" CREATE (r)<-[:WROTE]-(u) CREATE (r)<-[:NEWEST_REPLY]-(p) CREATE (r)-[:NEXT_REPLY]->(replies)"
```

My sense is that the logic I am attempting in either THEN statements is too complex for a CASE. Is there a more appropriate with to essentially do an if/else off of whether or not the NEWEST_REPLY relationship exists off of a specific Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This query should work for you:

```
MATCH (p:Post), (u:User)
WHERE p.id = $postId AND u.id = $userId
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[rel:NEWEST_REPLY]->(prevNewest:Reply)
CREATE (u)-[:WROTE]->(r:Reply {id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: "foo", createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime()})<-[:NEWEST_REPLY]-(p)
FOREACH(_ IN CASE WHEN rel IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END | DELETE rel CREATE (r)-[:NEXT_REPLY]->(prevNewest))
```

I asssume `postId` and `userId` are passed as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). Also, you should create [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Post(di)` and `:User(id)` to speed up the query.

Comment: That works great when replies already exists, but still fails when there isn't a prevNewest: "Failed to create relationship `  UNNAMED364`, node `prevNewest` is missing. If you prefer to simply ignore rows where a relationship node is missing, set 'cypher.lenient_create_relationship = true' in neo4j.conf"

Comment: On that note, this does the trick: MATCH (p:Post), (u:User)
WHERE p.id = $postId AND u.id = $userId
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[rel:NEWEST_REPLY]->(prevNewest:Reply)
CREATE (u)-[:WROTE]->(r:Reply {id: apoc.create.uuid(), body: "foo", createdAt: datetime(), updatedAt: datetime()})<-[:NEWEST_REPLY]-(p)
FOREACH(i in CASE WHEN NOT rel IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
DELETE rel CREATE (r)-[:NEXT_REPLY]->(prevNewest))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to delete any existing `[:NEWEST_REPLY]` rels:

```
MATCH (p:Post {id: $postId})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[rel:NEWEST_REPLY]->(previousNewestReply:Reply)
WITH p,previousNewestReply,
// create a collection of size 1 or 0
     CASE WHEN NOT rel IS NULL THEN [rel] ELSE [] END AS toBeDeleted

// loop through the collection
FOREACH( tbd IN toBeDeleted | DELETE tbd )


WITH p,previousNewestReply
.....
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but the idea is that there should always be only one NEWEST_REPLY. The bigger question for me is to do a CASE on whether or not that rel exists. I updated the original question with my progress and am currently mostly stuck on SyntaxErrors with my CASE.

Comment: I'm thinking that what I want to do is too complicated for a CASE.